# How to simplify work with class inheritance when a lot of arguments needed to be passed to c-tor?

Tags: design, c++, object-oriented-design, inheritance, language-features

Let's say I have class that used inside another class and uses inside some nested fields of it. To simplify the example I'll use trivial types. In reality it's something like `DataType dataType, Status const& isOnline, Session const& httpSession, FileLoaderInterface& fileLoader, Condition&& cancellationCondition`. While this is base class, I define more than 5 classes inheriting from it and first arg is reserved for concrete implementation.

```
class FooBase {
protected:
    FooBase(int implV,
      int i,
      std::string s,
      bool b,
      float f,
      double d){};

protected:
    int _implV;
    int _i;
    std::string _s;
    bool _b;
    float _f;
    double _d;
};

class FooChild : public FooBase {
public:
    FooChild(int i,
      std::string s,
      bool b,
      float f,
      double d)
        : FooBase(6, i, s, b, f, d){};
};
```

The issue is when I need to add or remove arg from base class c-tor, it cause cascade changes in all inherited classes, I'll be forced to change **all child classes c-tors and move/copy c-tors**. I have few ideas in mind.

First, to add common struct and use it for each class in hierarchy. In this case I don't like that the only way to initialize class instance is to use `initializer_list` like `FooChild foo({20, "foo", true, 0.5f, 0.5});`. Also it look not intuitive and you will not be suggested with argument list by your IDE.

```
class FooBase {
protected:
    using Prop = struct {
        int i;
        std::string s;
        bool b;
        float f;
        double d;
    };

    FooBase(int implV, Prop && prop){};

    ...
};

class FooChild : public FooBase {
public:
    FooChild(Prop && prop)
        : FooBase(6, std::move(prop)){};
};
```

Second, to use variadic template c-tor. Which takes even less code than previous one. The issue with it that you will know about a passed wrong arg only on compile time, but might be improved with custom sfinae checks:

```
class FooChild : public FooBase {
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    FooChild(Ts &&... args)
        : FooBase(6, std::forward<Ts>(args)...){};
};
```

Maybe there some smart way to do the same using only inheritance or design approaches I didn't know?

Comment: It seems you already have your solution. And with those contrived names like "Foo" or "Prop" there is no way to tell which approach is better suited, or if the problem may be caused by wrong usage of inheritance. I would also recommend to have a look on the [don't ask page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) of the help center, please note the recommendation about questions which already provide their answer along with the question, just expecting more answers.

Comment: Hey @DocBrown, thanks for reply! I don't have a solution actually. I only have few *thoughts* on *possible* design that's all. I'm not looking for **any** solution, I'm asking about specific language usage and best practices. I thought my question is pretty concrete, there nothing about proper inheritance or other possible aspects, I'm giving few *facts*, inheritance is used and c-tor has a lot of arguments. Doesn't it sound like a self complete issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself needing to add more data to your full inheritance stack over time, you should ask yourself whether inheritance makes sense in the first place.

It is odd for base classes to be extended that often. It defeats the purpose of inheritance and violates the O in SOLID.

You can mask that problem by wrapping everything up in an argument bundle but you may be better of rethinking the inheritance approach.

Can you really say that each of your sub-classes "is a" base class?